# error message in jquery form validation

Tags: jquery, regex

Here is my code for form validation in jquery, in which I have added alert class, when I click submit without entering values, `alert` class will be applied to each field but in my code this `alert` class is not working for email and password validation.

```
function validate() {
    var errorFlag = true;
    var userinput = $('#username').val();
    var mobilenumber=$('#mobnum').val();
    // var emailid=$('#mail').val();
    // var password=$('#pwd').val();
    var address1=$('#addr1').val();
    var address2=$('#addr2').val();

    var characterReg = /^([a-zA-Z]{2,30})$/;
    var numericReg=/^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$/;
    // var emailReg=/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    // var passReg=/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*$/;
    var addrReg = /^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9,\s]+\s*$/;

    var inputData = [{
        id : "username",
        regex : characterReg
    }, {
        id : "mobnum",
        regex : numericReg
    }, 
    // {
    //  id:"mail"
    //  regex: emailReg
    // },{
    //  id:"pwd"
    //  regex:passReg
    // },
    {
        id : "addr1",
        regex : addrReg
    }, {
        id : "addr2",
        regex : characterReg
    }];

    for(var index=0; index < inputData.length; index++) {

        var data = inputData[index];
        var regex = data.regex;
        if(!regex.test($('#' + data.id).val())) {
            errorFlag = false;
            $('#' + data.id).addClass('alert');
        } else {
            $('#' + data.id).removeClass('alert');
        }
    }
    return errorFlag;
}
```

any advice?

Comment: have u checked that control is actually reaching that point?

Comment: yes but its showing error in this line  regex: emailReg

Comment: which means that code next to the line producing error is not being executed..

Comment: @muhammad yes got it..but why i couldn't add alert box to email field..

Comment: you said its a class which means you are adding some styling to the field, not the alert message.

Comment: yes am adding alert class..which means red color box border..but its not applying to the email field..i can able to apply all other fields

Comment: have you fixed the regex problem..?

Comment: yes .. am getting correct output.. issue is alert class for that email field

Comment: open the inspector and run the same line where you are applying the class and then see the output.. also check that jquery can find that element or not?

Comment: @moksha your `emailReg` is matching empty strings. You can remove the greedy quantifier `?` at the end of your regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code basically has two issues:

**First:** you forgot to add comma in these two places:

```
{
  id:"mail"  <----------here
  regex: emailReg
},{
  id:"pwd" <----------here
  regex:passReg
}
```

**Second:** as for the email part you have a mistake in your regex, change this line:

```
var emailReg=/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
```

to this:

```
var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+)+(\.[\w-]{2,4})?)$/;
```

**Code: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fs4j2mv9/1/) <sup>(1)</sup>**

```js
function validate() {
  var errorFlag = true;
  var userinput = $('#username').val();
  var mobilenumber = $('#mobnum').val();
  var emailid = $('#mail').val();
  var password = $('#pwd').val();
  var address1 = $('#addr1').val();
  var address2 = $('#addr2').val();

  var characterReg = /^([a-zA-Z]{2,30})$/;
  var numericReg = /^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$/;
  var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+)+(\.[\w-]{2,4})?)$/;
  var passReg = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*$/;
  var addrReg = /^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9,\s]+\s*$/;

  var inputData = [{
    id: "username",
    regex: characterReg
  }, {
    id: "mobnum",
    regex: numericReg
  }, {
    id: "mail",
    regex: emailReg
  }, {
    id: "pwd",
    regex: passReg
  }, {
    id: "addr1",
    regex: addrReg
  }, {
    id: "addr2",
    regex: characterReg
  }];

  for (var index = 0; index < inputData.length; index++) {

    var data = inputData[index];
    var regex = data.regex;
    if (!regex.test($('#' + data.id).val())) {
      errorFlag = false;
      $('#' + data.id).addClass('alert');
    } else {
      $('#' + data.id).removeClass('alert');
    }
  }
  return errorFlag;
}

$('#btnGo').on('click', validate);
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.alert {
  border: 4px red solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="your username">
<input type="text" id="mobnum" placeholder="your mobile number">
<input type="text" id="mail" placeholder="your email">
<input type="text" id="pwd" placeholder="your password">
<input type="text" id="addr1" placeholder="your address - line 1">
<input type="text" id="addr2" placeholder="your address - line 2">
<button id="btnGo">Go</button>
```

---

**<sup>(1)</sup>** <sub>please take in consideration that providing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code within the question [or making a fiddle] will help much more</sub>